# constantly running queue

Tags: vb.net, queue

I'm not sure if this is the right approach but what I'm trying to do is create a queue that constantly runs so that I can keep adding things to it. Basically I would like to be able to add things to the queue and then it process it on a first come first served basis. I have the code below:

```
    Namespace Managers
    Public Class SQLQueueManager
        Public Shared Sqlitems As New Queue

        Public Sub StartProcessing()
            Dim t1 As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf Process)
            t1.Start()
        End Sub

        Public Shared Sub Process()
            Do
                SyncLock Sqlitems.SyncRoot
                    If Sqlitems.Count > 0 Then
                        SqlManager.ExecNonQuery(Sqlitems.Peek)
                        Sqlitems.Dequeue()
                    End If
                End SyncLock
            Loop
        End Sub

    End Class
End Namespace
```

i start this queue off using the following:

```
    Dim sqlT As Thread
    sqlT = New Thread(AddressOf SQLQueueManager.Process)
    sqlT.Start()
```

and i add items to the queue using:

```
SQLQueueManager.Sqlitems.Enqueue(...)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A custom approach like this can work.  Consider, perhaps, using `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` :

[ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem -- MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)